# Token del dispositivo con firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, fcm

tengo una duda respecto al token que se obtiene con FCM en flutter.
Tengo dos aplicaciones A Y B en el mismo proyecto de Firebase.
ambas necesitan el acceso a FCM, la cuestión radica que al instalar ambas app (A y B) en el mismo dispositivo, se obtiene el mismo toke.
¿Cómo hago para diferenciar entre las apps?

Comment: por el bundle identifier / package name

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario, fue de gran ayuda.